# How to set .gitlab-ci.yml to only run the tasks on one node and only update or push the repo to other nodes (docker-swarm)?

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, docker-swarm, gitlab-ci-runner

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file in my repo:

```
image: docker 

#services:
#  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build-prod:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - docker network create -d overlay reprox
  environment: master


deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - docker  
  script:
    - docker stack deploy -c ./site1/docker-compose.yml site1
    - docker stack deploy -c ./site2/docker-compose.yml site2 
    - docker stack deploy -c ./site3/docker-compose.yml site3
    - docker stack deploy -c ./reverse-proxy/docker-compose.yml proxy  
  environment: master
```

So my setup is 1 manager and 2 worker nodes and I only need to run build and deploy jobs on manager node, other nodes just need to have the repo, no need for running the bash commands on worker nodes.

I added a manager runner with "docker" tag and worker nodes with "runner" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `docker` tag. You can configure your workers to [work only on specific tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/#using-tags)

```
job1:
  tags:
    - dockernode_1
job2:
  tags:
    - dockernode_2
```

Your previously used `docker` tag was probably just a workaround (or from a tutorial) to make the runners work on all jobs. If you don't want a runner to care about tagging, you can make him [pick up all available jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/#runner-is-allowed-to-run-untagged-jobs).

Comment: Why should I remove the docker tag? Only the manager has that tag, I gave the worker a tag called "runner". So shouldn't it already work?

Comment: As things stand right now, It doesn't push the repo to the worker nodes. Only to the manager.

Comment: You'd have to create a dummy job (e.g. executing some command like `echo "success"`) if you want the repositories to only be checked out. Usually GitLab will not delete them afterwards, but you'll never know if that changes.
As I understand it your `manager`-node could keep the tag `docker` whilst the other nodes will have a tag which you attach to the dummy job.
If this is helpful I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to response. I added a test job to my stage to run simple echo on my worker nodes with the runner tag. It only did that job on one of my workers and the repo on the other one wasn't completely pushed, it went to "/home/gitlab-runner/builds/w3QexciJ/0/docker" there should be a folder with all the contents of the repo after /docker/ like on the other node. Also, it doesn't work, the same setup works fine on root, but for some reason all of the stacks won't work on my worker node (the one that pulled the repo correctly.).

Comment: Alright, I figured out the reason it doesn't work. There are to many folder, the repo folder should be directly in users home directory. But that is a problem I need to solve on my own. I guess I still don't know why it won't push the repo on one of my workers but I'll mark your anwers are helpful.

Comment: Sometimes I only use only one Gitlab CI runner to do the compiling + deploying work. You can use ssh to access any remote machines, and scp to transfer files to them.
Could that work for you?

Comment: I found a solution by just adding a simple job that runs a simple pwd command and as soon as it sees any job it will automatically first push the repo to the runner.